# Flask - how to develop and debug Azure Web App using provider-specific headers?

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I'm working on a small site using Flask/Azure web apps and would like to use Azure AD authentication, which is provided through the Azure portal web app settings.  I also need to access to Microsoft Graph using the same credentials once a user is logged in.  This seems easy enough when the app is actually set up on Azure:

request these headers as needed and make the requests.

X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN
X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ACCESS-TOKEN
X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-EXPIRES-ON
X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-REFRESH-TOKEN

I can't figure out how to do this part while I'm developing, however.  I don't want to have to write a bit, upload to Azure, catch a bug, then start all over again.  Is there a way to emulate the login/headers while developing?

Answer (score 0):

In local, you could [register an AD App in azure ad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application), give the `Delegated` permissions for Microsoft Graph, e.g. if you want to call this API - [`List users`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), you give the `User.Read.All` delegated permission, then use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to get the access token to call the API, for details see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?view=graph-rest-1.0). Once call the API successfully, it means the user could be able to call the API.

> I also need to access to Microsoft Graph using the same credentials once a user is logged in.

To call Microsoft Graph once the user logged in the web app, you need to configure the `https://microsoft.graph.com` in the `authsettings` -> `additionaloginparams` of your web app in the resource explorer, follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59606013/9455659).